# html attributes allowed in table

Tags: html, html-table

Could someone provide a list of html attributes that are allowed in a table? Not the normal ones like id, style, and class, but attributes that are specifically for tables like border, bgcolor (if it exists), and cellspacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want those in the standard or also non-standard ones?

I like the fact that this page differentiates, and it could be a good starting point:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa121597.htm

Comment: +1 Thanks, I found this link more comprehensive than the others.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [w3 doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html